# Is it possible to have a set of variables as exposure in a causal DAG?

Tags: causality, dag, distribution-identification, causal-diagram

I am working on identifiablity of a test (target) distribution based on the training distribution using interventional graphs. generally, I am wondering is it possible to consider a set of variables as exposure instead of one, e.g, X?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "exposure". Do you mean cause or effect? There's nothing, in either case, stopping you from defining your cause as a vector $X$ and your effect as a vector $Y.$

Comment: In causal analysis with DAGs, random variables (or nodes in DAGs) can be divided into three groups: outcome (dependent variable), exposure (independent variables that we want to see their effect on the outcome), and covariates (other variables) that they could be mediator, or collider, or cofounders.

Comment: Well, then, the short answer is, "Yes."